# PageObjects : How to call a function inside another?

Tags: javascript

```
Test = function(){
    this.functionOne = function(){
        // ...
    }
    this.functionTwo = function(){
        functionOne();
    }
}
module.exports = new Test();
```

However, this does not work and throws TypeError : functionOne is not a function at line 6.
I tried this.functionOne() and Test.functionOne and nothing worked, same error.
So how to call the functionOne in the functionTwo in a page object?

Comment: `I tried this.functionOne() [...] same error` are you sure? Because that's the fix.

Comment: Can you please give the working snippet where its giving error?

Comment: @NicholasTower Yes, also maybe it's not worth mentioning but functionTwo() is called from another file hence the module.exports = new Test();

Comment: You're probably calling it with the wrong `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`functionOne` is `undefined` inside `functionTwo`. You are adding `functionOne` as property of `this`. So to access this you need to use `this`. Here is the demo.

```js
const Test = function(){
    this.functionOne = function(){
        console.log("one is called")
    }
    this.functionTwo = function(){
        this.functionOne();
    }
}

let x = new Test();
x.functionTwo();  //"one is called"
```